# Which floor is redundant in floor(sqrt(floor(x)))?

Tags: math, floor

I have `floor(sqrt(floor(x)))`. Which is true:

1. The inner `floor` is redundant.
2. The outer `floor` is redundant.

Comment: Why call it a "Floor and Ceiling Question"?

Comment: Actually, the following very general result can be proved by extending Elazar Leibovich's idea below: If f(x) is any continuous, monotonically increasing function such that:
f(x) is an integer ==> x is an integer,
then floor(f(x)) = floor(f(floor(x)))
and similarly, ceiling(f(x)) = ceiling(f(ceiling(x))).

(Reference: Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik; Pg 71, Eq. 3.10).

Comment: My next question was to develop a general framework. Thanks for the reference. I will definitely take a look at the findings.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Btw your blog looks cool.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Obviously the outer floor is not redundant, since for example, `sqrt(2)` is not an integer, and thus `floor(sqrt(2))≠sqrt(2)`.

It is also easy to see that `sqrt(floor(x))≠sqrt(x)` for non-integer `x`. Since `sqrt` is a monotone function.

We need to find out whether or not `floor(sqrt(floor(x)))==floor(sqrt(x))` for all rationals (or reals).

Let us prove that if `sqrt(n)<m` then `sqrt(n+1)<m+1`, for integers `m,n`. It is easy to see that

```
n<m^2 ⇒ n+1 < m^2+1 < m^2+2m+1 = (m+1)^2
```

Therefor by the fact that `sqrt` is montone we have that

```
sqrt(n) < m -> sqrt(n+1) < m+1 -> sqrt(n+eps)<m+1 for 0<=eps<1
```

Therefor `floor(sqrt(n))=floor(sqrt(n+eps))` for all `0<eps<1` and integer `n`. Assume otherwise that `floor(sqrt(n))=m` and `floor(sqrt(n+eps))=m+1`, and you've got a case where `sqrt(n)<m+1` however `sqrt(n+eps)>=m+1`.

So, assuming the outer `floor` is needed, the inner `floor` is redundant.

To put it otherwise it is always true that

```
floor(sqrt(n)) == floor(sqrt(floor(n)))
```

What about inner `ceil`?

It is easy to see that `floor(sqrt(n)) ≠ floor(sqrt(ceil(n)))`. For example

```
floor(sqrt(0.001))=0, while floor(sqrt(1))=1
```

However you can prove in similar way that

```
ceil(sqrt(n)) == ceil(sqrt(ceil(n)))
```

Comment: Does your solution imply that an inner ceiling  would also be redundant?

Comment: I cant see any problem here. Unless somebody proves otherwise, this is correct.

Answer (score 18):

The inner one is redundant, the outer one of course not.

The outer one is not redundant, because the square root of a number x only results in an integer if x is a square number.

The inner one is redundant, because the square root for any number in the interval [x,x+1[ (where x is an integer) always lies within the interval [floor(sqrt(x)),ceil(sqrt(x))[ and therefore you don't need to floor a number before taking the square root of it, if you are only interested the integer part of the result.

Comment: There were a lot of good proofs but this one is the sweetest. Thanks.

Comment: Who said there's no whole integer in [sqrt(x),sqrt(x+1)]? If for example sqrt(x)==0.9 and sqrt(x+1)=1.2, then the result of floor(sqrt(floor(x))) might be different than floor(sqrt(x))

Comment: I'm glad you like it. After reading all the different and well done actual proofs I thought my explanation might be too informal for some tastes.

Comment: Wow. Is there a hole in the solution?

Comment: @Elazar: I wrote [sqrt(x),sqrt(x)+1[ and not [sqrt(x),sqrt(x+1)[, but even then you are right (though, your example is wrong). I've corrected the interval to what I actually meant. The sqrt(x) and sqrt(x+1) of any integer x lies within the same integer interval.

Answer (score 5):

Intuitively I believe the inner one is redundant, but I can't prove it.

You're not allowed to vote me down unless you can provide a value of x that proves me wrong.  8-)

**Edit:** See v3's comment on this answer for proof - thanks, v3!

Comment: I too tried out examples and feel it in my gut that the inner one is redundant but its damn hard to prove that i am correct.

Comment: Indeed. There was an answer saying the inner one is redundant, but before I could upvote it it got downvoted and deleted. Still, I believe that's the case.

Comment: Can't you just say that floor(sqrt(x)) only changes value on integer values of x? If x is not an integer, then flooring it won't change the integer part of the square root.

Answer (score 4):

The inner floor is redundant

Comment: there, i'll give ya the ten points lost :) I was surprised Richie got that many upvotes for an answer like that...

Comment: Anybody who downvotes me, needs to downvote Richie. I give my answer before him.

Answer (score 4):

The inner floor is redundant.  A proof by contradiction:

Assume the inner floor is not redundant.  That would mean that:

```
floor(sqrt(x)) != floor(sqrt(x+d))
```

for some x and d where floor(x) = floor(x+d).  Then we have three numbers to consider:
a = sqrt(x), b = floor(sqrt(x+d)), c = sqrt(x+d).  b is an integer, and a < b < c.
That means that a^2 < b^2 < c^2, or x < b^2 < x+d.  But if b is an integer,
then b^2 is an integer.  Therefore floor(x) < b^2, and b^2 <= floor(x+d), and then floor(x) < floor(x+d).  But we started by assuming floor(x) = floor(x+d).  We've reached a contradiction, so our assumption is false, and the inner floor is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

If x is an integer then the inner floor is redundant.

If x is not an integer then neither are redundant.

Comment: the question really is why for the second part.

Comment: So much bla-bla around, while Macker only got it right and concise.

Comment: the bla bla was trying to convince ourselves that it is true.

Comment: Strange that you say it's wrong but have agreed with the same conclusions in your choice of answer. I'm confused. You didn't ask for a proof in your question btw.

Comment: I am sorry the question is still open. Could you edit it with your proof?

Comment: Actually, Ned Batchelder has convinced me that inner is always redundant now, well done Ned.

Answer (score 3):

The outer floor is not redundant. Counterexample: x = 2.

floor(sqrt(floor(2))) = floor(sqrt(2)) = floor(1.41...)

Without the outer floor the result would be 1.41...

Answer (score 2):

If the inner floor were not redundant, then we would expect that  floor(sqrt(n)) != floor(sqrt(m)), where m = floor(n)

note that n - 1 < m <= n.  m is always less than or equal to n

floor(sqrt(n)) != floor(sqrt(m)) requires that the values of sqrt(n) and sqrt(m) differ by at least 1.0

however, there are no values n for which the sqrt(n) differs by at least 1.0 from sqrt(n + 1), since for all values between 0 and 1 the sqrt of that value is < 1 by definition.

thus, for all values n, the floor(sqrt(n)) == floor(sqrt(n + 1)).  This is in contradiction to the original assumption.

Thus the inner floor is redundant.

Comment: "floor(sqrt(n)) != floor(sqrt(m)) requires that the values of sqrt(n) and sqrt(m) differ by at least 1.0" doesn't seem to be true, if sqrt(n) = 0.999 and sqrt(m) = 1, their different by far less than 1, however floor(sqrt(n))!=floor(sqrt(m))

Comment: "note that n <= m < n + 1"
That doesn't seem to be true, since floor(n) can be < n

Answer (score 0):

If `n^2 <= x < (n+1)^2` where `n` is an integer, then

1. `n <= sqrt(x) < n+1`, so `floor(sqrt(x)) = n`;
2. `n^2 <= floor(x) < (n+1)^2`, so `n <= sqrt(floor(x)) < n+1`, so `floor(sqrt(floor(x))) = n`.

Therefore, `floor(sqrt(floor(x))) = floor(sqrt(x))`, which implies the **inner** floor is redundant.